# How can you assign a batch file to a special key on a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, batch, cmd.exe, hotkeys

I'm trying to use the special keys (play,pause,next,prev, internet) on my keyboard to open select batch files and im having trouble doing this with Windows or a 3rd party program

I understand you can change what media program is opened by going to default programs but that only lets you open media apps.

I tried assigning a keyboard shortcut to a batch file shortcut but that only lets you pick traditional keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl + Alt + O which is plausible but if I'm using a program that already has that key combo I think that program will intercept it like a bad pass

Any apps that can do this or how to do this without an app is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), a scripting language specially customized to map keypresses to scripts (in your case, the keypress would invoke the batch file).  You'd have to learn a bit about AutoHotKey to make this work, but it's a tool well worth learning about.

This should enable you to figure out how to identify the presses on those specific keys.
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/53254-how-to-send-the-special-key-playpause-to-contro/